# How to Create a New B2C Tenant with Azure.ResourceManager or other Nuget Library

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm aiming to create Azure B2C tenants programmatically whenever a new customer for my application is registered as this application would support multitenancy. The customers would also have the ability to instantiate many tenants for themselves to logically segment access to resources.

From what I can see there's a way to do this via the Azure REST API though I'd rather use one of the nuget packages for programmatically managing Azure such as Azure.ResourceManager. Is this possible or must I use the REST API to accomplish this?

This question's answer hints that it might be possible but never demonstrates it directly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403043/5229138

Answer (score 0):

To create Azure AD B2C tenant, create an Azure AD Application and grant API permission like below:

[image]

Make use of below c# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Security;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string clientId = "XXXX"; // Replace with your Azure AD application's client ID
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID"; // Replace with your Azure AD tenant ID
        string username = "UserName"; // Replace with the user's username
        string password = "****"; // Replace with the user's password
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }; // Define the desired scopes

        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();

        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, securePassword)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        if (authResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authResult.AccessToken))
        {
            string accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
            Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + accessToken);

            // Now, use the access token to create a B2C tenant
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/ruktenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2023-01-18-preview";

                string jsonContent = "{\"location\": \"United States\",\"sku\": {\"name\": \"Standard\",\"tier\": \"A0\"},\"properties\": {\"createTenantProperties\": {\"displayName\": \"Contoso\",\"countryCode\": \"US\",\"isGoLocalTenant\": true}}}";

                var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                // Set the Authorization header with the obtained access token
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

                var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Success
                    Console.WriteLine("B2C tenant created successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle error
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to acquire an access token.");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

***After few minutes, the Azure AD B2C tenant created successfully like below:***

[image]